# Proof verification that a set in a metric space $A$ is closed iff $ A = cl A$

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$This is an exercise from Conway's A Course in Point Set Topology. I constantly use the following Proposition 1.1.13 (P1.1.13): Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq X$, then

a) $x\in\int A\iff\exists r>0[B(x;r)\subseteq A]$
b) $x\in\cl A\iff\forall r>0[B(x;r)\cap A \ne\varnothing]$

Also, a set $G\subseteq X$ is said to be open if $\forall x\in G\exists r>0[B(x;r)\subseteq G]$. And a set $F\subseteq X$ is said to be closed if $X\setminus F$ is open. Where $B(x;r)=\{y\in X: d(x,y)<r\}$ is called an open ball about $x\in X$ of radius $r>0$.

The Exercise 1.7 which is proving Proposition 1.1.15(a): Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq X$. Then $A$ is closed $\iff A = \cl A$.

Proof. $(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $A$ is closed and let $x\in A$ be arbitrary. Suppose $x\notin\cl A$, then by P1.1.13(b) we can choose an $r>0$ such that $B(x;r)\cap A=\varnothing$. So since $x\in A$ it implies that $x\notin B(x;r)$, which is a contradiction, thus $x\in\cl A$, as $x$ was arbitrary $A\subseteq\cl A$. Now, let $x\in\cl A$ be arbitrary, and suppose that $A$ is closed. Given that $A$ is closed and $A\subseteq A$, since $\cl A=\cap \{F: F\,is\,closed\,and\,A\subseteq F\}$, then $x\in A$, as $x$ was arbitrary it implies that $\cl A \subseteq A$. Hence we can conclude that $A=\cl A$.

$(\leftarrow$) Suppose $A=\cl A$. Given that the closure of any set is closed, then $\cl A$ is closed, implying that $A$ is closed. $\square$

Is this proof right?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `\newcommand{}{}` and `\operatorname` to be able to write `\int` and get $\rm{int}$ rendered nicely for you as if it were a default command. I've done this in your post

Comment: To verify your post we should know how you're defining "$A$ is closed"

Comment: @FShrike thanks for the edit. I just included the definition of closed and open sets in this contex as suggested.

Comment: I’m a little uncertain about your proof - you skip steps. Why does $x\in\mathrm{cl}(A)$ imply $x\in A$ without further comment? Oh and by the way, the closure of a set is always closed

Comment: @FShrike I just added an edit specifying why. Basically as the closure is the intersection of the sets of which A is a subset and are closed, A itself satisfies this condition, thus any element of the closure must also be in A itself. Is that reasoning right?

Comment: You’re already identifying the closure with a closed set. That’s correct, but I suspect it is what you are being asked to prove

Comment: In that specific part I'm using as givens that $A$ is closed and trying to show that $cl A\subseteq A$, then I can let $x\in cl A$ be arbitrary and show that $x\in A$. Should I probably be more specific in the proof? Thank you.

Comment: It just boils down to whether or not you're allowed to use "closure is closed". That's all. The proof itself is perfectly correct